# Blocked Vs obstructed

Tags: word-choice, difference, word-difference

Which word is an appropriate choice below?

> They are trying to clear roads **blocked/obstructed** by fallen trees.

The confusion is because, in the context, both word choices seem correct. Both means to hinder the movement.

Answer (score 5):

They are mostly synonymous, but "blocked" implies that passage is impossible, while "obstructed" is more ambiguous as to whether passage is impossible, or simply more difficult.

Comment: It's a good answer, but could you provide some examples that help illustrate the difference?

Comment: Would “clogged” be appropriate here?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I would say no, *clogged* usually refers to pipes that are stopped up. Or some sort of tube that contains a substance preventing liquid from flowing through it smoothly. *Clogged* could also be used to describe a road, but I think it only works you're describing traffic, as caused by vehicles - like "The road was *clogged* with cars". I think cars are analogous to gunk in a pipe because they might move eventually. But fallen trees on the road are static; they will stay there until someone removes them.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  "Clogged" could be used figuratively -- as Mixolydian says, it's like a blocked pipe.  So if you wanted to say the path was *clogged* by fallen trees it's like comparing it to a blocked pipe.  For example:  *The road ahead was **clogged** with soldiers returning from the front lines*, which suggests the narrator is unable to move in the desired direction.